# What is the win probabiity of an ice hockey team being down 1-0 at the end of the second period?

Tags: statistics, ice-hockey

I heard following hypothesis about ice-hockey statistics;

-20 min left (i.e. whole third period)
-situation is 0-1

I was told the team that is trailing, has bigger probability to win the game.
Has anyone seen such statistics to prove if this is the case?

Comment: Could you provide some information as to where you saw this? On the face of it, it sounds like complete rubbish, and extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.

Comment: I heard it from the radio.

Comment: Was it a general statement by the commentator, or specific to one of the teams involved? It's hard to believe it's true in general. But very possible if a team can't hold their lead, or surges back in the third

Comment: A site with per-period scores would make this easy to analyze.  I found one which shows it's not true for all teams trailing at the start of the third, but it doesn't break out "0-1" scores versus down by 4, so it's not that useful.

Comment: Question - are you counting a "win" as a regulation win only? or do OT / Shootout wins count as "wins", too?

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This is currently a preliminary answer - perhaps more to come depending on what the OP wants.

---

Going by the results from the 2020/2021 NHL season (until 7th May) there have been a total of 67 games where the game was 1-0 to either team at the end of the second period.

Of these, there were 6 games where that 1-0 deficit was overturned by the other team **in regulation**, giving an 8.96% overturn rate - or a roughly 1 in 11 chance.

So, statistically, the team trailing 1-0 at that point are significantly less likely to win<sup>1</sup>.

These games were:

| Date | Game | End of P2 Score | Final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14th Feb 2021 | [Montreal Canadiens v Toronto Maple Leafs](https://www.espn.co.uk/nhl/game/_/gameId/401272327) | 0 : 1 | 2 : 1 |
| 19th Mar 2021 | [New York Rangers v Washington Capitals](https://www.espn.co.uk/nhl/game/_/gameId/401272570) | 1 : 0 | 1 : 2 |
| 24th Mar 2021 | [Calgary Flames v Ottawa Senators](https://www.espn.co.uk/nhl/game/_/gameId/401272603) | 1 : 0 | 1 : 3 |
| 4th Apr 2021 | [Minnesota Wild v Vegas Golden Knights](https://www.espn.co.uk/nhl/game/_/gameId/401272687) | 0 : 1 | 2 : 1 |
| 20th Apr 2021 | [Montreal Canadiens v Edmonton Oilers](https://www.espn.co.uk/nhl/game/_/gameId/401272801) | 1 : 0 | 1 : 4 |
| 1st May 2021 | [Los Angeles Kings v Anaheim Ducks](https://www.espn.co.uk/nhl/game/_/gameId/401272887) | 0 : 1 | 2 : 1 |

---

1. Obviously, as this data is coming from the middle of the 2020/21 season of the NHL, this is just a subset of all possible Ice Hockey games - so the *real* value is likely to be something different.

---

I must give credit to [this site](https://www.scoreboard.com/uk/nhl/results/) which listed out all of the games, plus their period by period scores, in which I scraped together the information into a spreadsheet...